# How to ease bots (AI) management and configuration?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, server-administration

I play CS:GO with my roommate against bots and we like to make custom games, say 2 CT's (us) vs 5 T's. Doing this in CS:GO requires some console commands. My question is, can we batch these commands somehow, or make a script that runs on server startup? The goal being to jump right into our custom setup without typing in a bunch of console commands and then restarting the server by hand.

Comment: I don't know the CS:GO config system, but in CS 1.6 you could use a simple bind in your config.cfg file, like `bind B "mp_autoteambalance 0;add_bot_T;add_bot_T;add_bot_T;add_bot_T;add_bot_T;sv_restart 1"`

Comment: I can confirm the above will work, you can also make a custom config file eg: customgames.cfg in your SteamApps\CSGO\cfg folder and execute it in console by running "exec customgames.cfg"

Answer (score 1):

LorenzoDB was on track although probably a touch more complex than it needed to be.

The most straightforward solution would be to create a config file with a custom name. And inside of that config file put all the command you would manually type.

Then when you want to play, load up CS:GO and do `exec my_script.cfg` in the console. It'll just run all of your commands batched and you should be good to go.

You could also bind it to a button on your keyboard (say an unused f key or something, but I'd lean towards a script you'd execute (per my first suggestion). You probably only need to run it at the start and then the match would just go from there.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have a file called *server.cfg*

The server.cfg file can be found under \csgo\cfg. (make it if it doesn't exist)'

Here is an example of a very simple server.cfg file:

```
hostname "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive Dedicated Server"
rcon_password "yourrconpassword"
sv_password "" //Only set this if you intend to have a private server!
```

From here, you can add additional commands to customize your server's game play experience:

```
mp_freezetime 5 //The amount of time players are frozen to buy items
mp_join_grace_time 15 //The amount of time players can join teams after a round has started
mp_match_end_restart 0 // Defines whether a map should be restarted after a game has ended 
sv_cheats 0 //This should always be set, so you know it's not on
sv_lan 0 //This should always be set, so you know it's not on
//**The bot commands below are mostly default with the exception of 
bot_difficulty 1
bot_chatter "off"
bot_join_after_player 1
bot_quota 10
bot_quota_mode "fill"
//**The following commands manage kicks and bans
exec banned_user.cfg
exec banned_ip.cfg
writeid
writeip
```

Set every command you want to use in this file and it will load at the start of the server.

For what you want I think it is `mp_autobalance 0; add_bot_T;add_bot_T;add_bot_T;add_bot_T;add_bot_T;sv_restart 1`

If you don't want to set all the command in this file, make another file "GameModeName".cfg and type in the server.cfg file: "exec 'GameModeName".cfg